# Unable to retrieve AWS scaling policy information from ec2_scaling_policy module in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, ansible

I'm trying to create an AWS scaling policy and attach a metric alarm to it. From what I understand, the ec2_metric_alarm module needs the ARN of the scaling policy so that it can associate itself with it.

However, I can't seem to get the ARN after creating a new scaling policy from the ec2_scaling_policy module's output. Currently I'm trying to register the result of the ec2_scaling policy module. For example, my playbook looks something like this:

```
- name: Create scaling policy and associate it with autoscaling group
  ec2_scaling_policy:
    state: present
    region: us-east-1
    name: "test-scaleup-policy"
    adjustment_type: "ChangeInCapacity"
    asg_name: "test-asg"
    scaling_adjustment: 1
    min_adjustment_step: 1
    cooldown: 300
  register: sp_result

- name: Debug result of scaling policy creation
  debug: var=sp_result

- name: Create metric alarm and associate it with autoscaling policy
  action:
    module: ec2_metric_alarm
    state: present
    alarm_actions: ["{{ sp_result.arn }}"]
    etc...
```

The debug module prints this:

```
TASK: [Debug] ***************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
   "sg_result": {
      "changed": false, 
      "invocation": {
      "module_args": "", 
      "module_name": "ec2_scaling_policy"
}}}
```

According to [this merged pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/7829), the ARN should be included in the data the module returns. I'm still pretty new to Ansible, so I'm wondering if I'm trying to capturing this information in the wrong way, e.g. using register when I should be using something else? Otherwise, is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using?  That change is merged into the devel branch but none of the releases yet.

Comment: @thinkmassive Turns out that was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That change is merged into Ansible's devel branch but none of the releases yet.